# Is this possible to display RTF text+ images in crystal report

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

RTF data saved in varbinary sql column. When i put blob field in Crystal report, It display nothing.

I try to save formatted text RTF into nvarchar it display in CR RTF field.

Also images directly saved into var-binary and display in blob field.

But when both text and images saved into varbinary then who to display it into crystal report?

What i am doing wrong.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you please give me some more description with image or demo?

Comment: I did not know RTF had support to images. But you can set a text field in Crystal to be treated as RTF. Right click, format object, paragraph, text interpretation = RTF. This does not fully answer your question, but i thougth it could be usefull.

Comment: @RahulDubey more description here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834082/how-to-display-formated-text-with-images-from-sql-database-in-crystal-report

Comment: @heringer i am using CRforVS_13_0_12 version but there is no option for text field to be treated as RTF.


but

If i have SQL field with RTF text and data type NVARCHAR then CRforVS_13_0_12 allowed me to change text interpretation = RTF

Comment: @RahulDubey did you get that link any extra information or is there any need to update question

Comment: I don't know is this link is helpful for you or not. Here is http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/580812/displayplusimageplusinpluscrystalplusreportplusfro